# How do I prevent my android app from constantly getting cached

Tags: applications, google-pixel, cache

Excuse the novice question.

I've got a website which has constantly changing content. I've had an android mobile app made for me (by web2application.com) which in theory should just open the website in a frame- pretty simple stuff.

However what seems to happen is the content doesn't actually update. Even when the website content changes, the mobile app still shows the same old content. If I clear the cache for the app it fixes it and the new content is shown.

Is there a way to force an android device to not use the cache for the app at all?

I'm using a Google Pixel 4a but I think there's a similar issue on other android devices.

Comment: What happens if you use a regular web browser app like chrome? Do the site update properly or does it also show outdated content? If it also shows outdated content you should check web server configuration. It can define how often client should check for updates and how (there are different ways or headers that can be used to check for updates and only load the content if it had been changed).

Comment: @Robert Yeah it all works fine on a regular web browser apps. It stays up-to-date as it should.

Comment: Then this is a problem of the app created by web2application.com because autor-generated web apps mainly base on the web browser which is provided by Android (usually the WebView is provided by Chrome or the Google WebView provide which is effectively Chrome again). May be they set the wrong options?

Comment: I've spoken with web2application.com and they are determined they haven't got any caching set up. Frankly I don't believe them.